# Is there a smart/better way to updating table values dynamically, with potential dependencies?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Smart way of SQL updating table values dynamically with dependencies?

I've been trying in my program to limit the amount of stored procedures. I have by inserting, and deleting my tables/rows dynamically, depending on the variable, I call my stored procedure with are null or not.

Though, I keep hitting a wall when it comes to updating, since I also want to be able to update variables with null.

Table design:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Addresses
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    address_line nvarchar(50) NULL,
    city nvarchar(50) NULL,
    zipcode nvarchar(50) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Jobs
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    job_name nvarchar(50) NULL,
    job_salary nvarchar(50) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.People
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    first_name nvarchar(50) NULL,
    last_name nvarchar(50) NULL,
    address_id int NOT NULL,
    job_id int NULL

    CONSTRAINT [FK_people_addresses] 
        FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES Addresses (id)
    CONSTRAINT [FK_people_jobs] 
        FOREIGN KEY (job_id) REFERENCES Jobs (id)
)
```

(This is only an example. The main database has more complexity to it)

I want to be able to update a single person and his dependencies dynamically, depending on what has changed.

The only solution I've found is either update everything, even when no changes have been made to either the main table or its dependencies, or make separate queries (potentially bad practice) on each variable on each table to see if updating is needed

Current solution example

```sql
--example

--update job values for person with an given
--@JobId, @NewJobName (can be null), @NewJobSalary (can be null)

--is job id != null (then the table needs updateing)
IF (@JobId != NULL)

BEGIN
  --job name, if old != new
    IF ((SELECT Jobs.name
        FROM Jobs
        WHERE Jobs.id = @JobId) != @NewJobName)

      BEGIN
        UPDATE Jobs
        SET name = @JobName
        WHERE Jobs.id = @JobId
      END

    --Update Job Salary, if old != new
    IF ((SELECT Jobs.salary
        FROM Jobs
        WHERE Jobs.id = @JobId) != @NewJobSalary)

      BEGIN
        UPDATE Jobs
        SET name = @JobName
        WHERE Jobs.id = @JobId
      END
END
```

So my question is this - within this scenario, is there a way to do this smarter?

Is it potentially possible to do 1 sub query/sub stored procedure for the main table that returns 1 row, and assigns all values to parameters (and potentially dependent tables), so more simple if statements can be stacked to see what needs to updated, and update it accordingly.

```
IF (@QueryJobName != @NewJobName)
```

Or is there a smarter or better way to dynamically update a single table row's values dynamically if need be, with null values as well?

Comment: `!= @NewJobSalary`  Not an answer, but something to keep in mind is that null never equals anything - not even another null. So your current solution won't behave as expected if either values is `null`. Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57b5d2a22bc3a9523d45a5c83e58198e

Comment: huh... didetn know that... honestly never thought about that... thanks. so... this would be a better solution for compareing nulls? `IF ((ISNULL(@QueryJobName, '0')) != (ISNULL(@NewJobName, '0')))`

Answer (score 0):

Not to attack the premise of the question, but why store these records in multiple tables?  Store them once then reference these additional tables as views or stored procedures.

It just *feels* more like a data engineering problem...

Comment: This should go as comment section to the question, it does not answer the question raised by user.

Comment: its just an example. my main program the tables are: People, Tenants, Employees. where ere people is still the main table that stores refrence to the other.